# How to load .dat files to oracle database

Tags: data-warehouse, etl, business-intelligence

I have .DAT files extracted from telecom switch.

I want to upload this file to an Oracle server using IBM data-stage ETL tool.

Unfortunately these files are not readable format.

This is a picture of the .DAT file when opened in notepad:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not all .dat files are the same and it's hard to determine from the screenshot what the format is.

If you extracted that from a telecom switch, you will need to contact the telecom vendor to ask if they have a data provider for the file format and use that provider to make a connection to the .dat file from within your ETL tools.

If they don't have a provider, which is entirely plausible, you will need to extract the data in another format such as .csv. Again, contact the vendor to see if that is an option

Comment: I haven't way to contact vendor, So that i asked this question.

Comment: What is the vendor, maybe there is online support available? What is the switch brand and type?

Comment: This is Huawei GGSN CDRs

Comment: If they're CDRs, they're more than likely to be in ASN.1 format. Try opening in an ASN.1 viewer